# How can i add separator menu in xml for toplinks in magento

Tags: magento, menu

I want to add separator menu in xml file so that it shows in top links of magento.

How can i do this?

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about a separator menu but if you want to change or add a separator you can do it  like this:

`<default>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <!-- set this up as the top links separator -->
        <block type="core/text" name="top.links.separator">
            <action method="setText">
                <text>&lt;li&gt;|&lt;/li&gt;</text>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</default>`

Comment: Thanks, but it is not working for me. don't know why.